# reverse triangle in python 2.7.15

Tags: python

I am trying to create a reverse triangle in python 2.7.15 that looks like this:

```
**********
*********
********
*******
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

So far my code is this:

```
for x in range (1,11):
    for spaces in range (1,11-x):
        print " ",

    for y in range (1, x+1):
        print "*",
    print
```

but it spits out this triangle:

```
   *
                * *
              * * *
            * * * *
          * * * * *
        * * * * * *
      * * * * * * *
    * * * * * * * *
  * * * * * * * * *
* * * * * * * * * *
```

How do I get python to do it inverted?

Answer (score 1):

If that's your expected output, then you can do:

```
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    print('*' * i)
```

In python 2, as yours is in:

```
for i in range(10, 0, -1):
    print '*' * i
```

Which can be shortened to:

```
print(*('*' * i for i in range(10, 0, -1)), sep='\n')
```

...Which unpacks each line into a single print function and adds a new line between each. This shortened version only works with Python3. *(I also recommended upgrading to python 3 if possible)*

The ideas behind this are the following:

1. Strings can be multiplied to copy them
2. Each line is a repeated `*`
3. So... use a reverse range: `range(10, 0, -1) to get the decrease for each line
4. Multiply the string `*` by the number from the range each time.

Comment: Unable to access python right now, so please correct me if the answer doesn't work